# Nuxt/Vuejs Event to fire when page done rendering all the components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to fire an event when page is done with rendering all the components. I have tried page mounted event but this fires only for the first time, I need to fire an event when the route changes on client side and new component is done rendering.

Answer (score 0):

How about using updated . I used that for data changing state . Hope you get some help from this tips

```
updated: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that will run only after the
    // entire view has been re-rendered
  })
}
```